# Should I cut control joints into a 10' by 12' shed slab?

Tags: concrete, construction, shed

I'm building a 10'x12' shed on a new concrete slab. The plans call for a 4" slab (thicker at the edge).

My question is about control joints. It seems that 10'x12' is right on the edge of what should be done as a single piece. What do you all think? Should I cut a few so that I have 4 5'x6' areas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related reading material: http://www.cement.org/learn/concrete-technology/concrete-construction/contraction-control-joints-in-concrete-flatwork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is largely a matter of opinion, but in my experience a 10x12 slab will almost certainly crack. There's no question but that I'd cross-cut it, at least. I might even go so far as to split the length into thirds. Clean, straight lines are preferable to jagged ones, and you can always fill your cuts with caulk to keep the floor surface intact.

```
 _________________________
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|-------------------------|
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|-------------------------|
|            |            |
|            |            |
|____________|____________|
```

Comment: But do be sure to put wire and re-bar in your slab so that if it does crack that there is minimal shifting between the separate parts.

Comment: How deep should the cuts be? Could one use a standard circular saw with a "concrete blade"? How soon after the pour should the cuts be made?

Comment: Sorry, but I won't be writing up a primer on control joints. It's been done [one](http://www.cement.org/learn/concrete-technology/concrete-construction/contraction-control-joints-in-concrete-flatwork), [two](https://www.concretenetwork.com/concrete/slabs/controljoints.htm), [three](https://www.concretedecor.net/decorativeconcretearticles/vol-2-no-4-decemberjanuary-2002/decorative-control-joints/) times already, at least. :)